# Scrape tables with Beautiful Soup and pandas

Tags: python, object, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, bots

I've been trying to scrape a table with beautiful soup to put the variables into an object but it's returning me the result in three objects. I've tried to put them in a list but I need them together in one object

```
for table in priceTable:
    td= table.find_all('td')
    row=[i.text for i in td]
    print(name, row)
```

And this returns me the result in three diferent objects
`[example1][example2][example3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be printing each object separately. If you would like them to print together, or be in one object for future code to be executed, then try putting each result into a list and then printing the list.

```
foolist = []

for table in priceTable:
    td= table.find_all('td')
    row=[i.text for i in td]
    foolist.append(row)

print(foolist)

for foo in foolist:
    foo += " bar"
```

Comment: Thanks you bro, Im super noob at programming

Comment: @JoséManuelRodríguez Sure thing, Bro. Feel free to ask if you need any more help with this project.